# Tomcat $CATALINA_HOME environment variable in openshift

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, catalina, opengts

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 566 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping jbossews cartridge
remote: Sending SIGTERM to jboss:37420 ...
remote: Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Repairing links for 1 deployments
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 836ffbc
remote: Skipping Maven build due to absence of pom.xml
remote: /var/lib/openshift/56938f232d5271a6d000013b
remote: Buildfile: /var/lib/openshift/56938f232d5271a6d000013b/app-root/runtime/
repo/OpenGTS_2.6.0/build.xml
remote:
remote: BUILD FAILED
remote: /var/lib/openshift/56938f232d5271a6d000013b/app-root/runtime/repo/OpenGT
S_2.6.0/build.xml:66: /var/lib/openshift/56938f232d5271a6d000013b/app-root/runti
me/repo/OpenGTS_2.6.0/OPENSHIFT_PRIMARY_CARTRIDGE_DIR does not exist.
remote:
remote: Total time: 0 seconds
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'build' for 5
6938f232d5271a6d000013b application tomcat
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with t
he '--trace' option.
To ssh://56938f232d5271a6d000013b@tomcat-winnetou.rhcloud.com/~/git/tomcat.git/
   07d33ce..836ffbc  master -> master
```

So my question is that Can I put environment variable in OpenShift like this:

```
 $CATALINA_HOME=OPENSHIFT_PRIMARY_CARTRIDGE_DIR or 
 $CATALINA_HOME=OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_DIR or 
 $CATALINA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jbossews-2.0
```

So please tell me what is right environment variable  value for `CATALINA_HOME`?

Comment: Thanks Eric B. for editing the question.I am newone on the stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks also Ali Dehghani  but I need answer for this question.

Comment: Has anybody deployed OpenGTS_2.6.0 project on OpenShift online?I am also trying to do this but it is not working.

Comment: What is the solution of this question ? I have the same issue